# How to use a .include?-like method in the File class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class

I'm still learning Ruby so far and working on a small gem that allows you to do something as long as the current file your in includes a certain attribute (in my case ''). I took a look at some of the `File` class methods and never came across anything I was looking for. I do realize the popular `Array` method `.include?`, and I'm wondering if there's a method for doing this in a bigger scale, which is applying it to the `File` class. Can anyone point out a `File` class method or script that does this?

Example:

```
# The Array class method scans the array for an item
arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
if arr.include?('foo')
  # (insert text)
end
```

What I need to do:

```
if File.include?('')
  # My code
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look:

```
if File.read(filename).include? str
  # do your thing
end
```

Caution: this code reads entire file into memory. You better not apply it to huge files.

This is a more efficient way.

```
def my_include? filename, str
  File.open(filename, "r") do |file|
    file.each do |line|
      return true if line.include?(str)
    end
  end
  false
end
```

Comment: Thanks. However it would be nice to be able to use it in larger files, it'll do for little things. Is there any relatively quick ways to make it not store the _entire_ file in memory? Very much thanks for the help, I'll now be able to make my gem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to find the first match against the file and stop there, without having to read the entire file:

```
File.foreach(filename).enum_for(:grep, /foo/).first
```